# How to display dates in python like a language format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file called weather. I got the maximum and minimum temperatures using pandas:

```
read = pandas.read_csv('weather.csv')
dates = df['DATE'].values.tolist()
# get max & min from column TX
maxtemp = read['TX'].max()
mintemp = read['TX'].min()
```

Then I created the variables maxdate and mindate to represent the minimum degrees and maximum degrees dates

```
maxdate = dates[maxtemp]
mindate = dates[mintemp]
```

Now I'm printing this:

```
print("Max temperature was", float(maxtemp) / 10.0, "degrees on", maxdate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
print("Min temperature was", float(mintemp) / 10.0, "degrees on", mindate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

My output is now:

```
Max temperature was 36.8 degrees on 19020104 DD-MMM-YYYY
Min temperature was -11.3 degrees on 20150410 DD-MMM-YYYY
```

However, I want to convert it into human language format, like this:

```
Max temperature was 36.8 degrees on 4 january 1902
```

Comment: @Prune What's wrong with my question exactly then?

Comment: Date conversion is well-documented, straightforward to find with a browser search.  You've shown no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @Prune Well I didn't find anything with my browser search, otherwise I wouldn't ask my question on here would I?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it by using `to_datetime` before `print`

```
read.date=pd.to_datetime(read.date,format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d %B %Y')
```